# more precision on the barplot pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to change the graph to show the 14.047 is less than 15, more decimal precision

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn, openright]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}


% Define bar chart colors
%
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        y tick label style={
                /pgf/number format/fixed
                },
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=12pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {\#iterations},
        symbolic x coords={topology1,topology2,topology3,topology4,topology5},
        xtick = data,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.12,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=20,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
 ]
        \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none}]
            coordinates {(topology1, 15) (topology2,12) (topology3,11)(topology4, 9) (topology5,9) };
        \addplot[style={ppurple,fill=ppurple,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(topology1,18.047) (topology2,15.047) (topology3,14.047)(topology4, 12.047) (topology5,12.047)};

        \addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(topology1,18.047) (topology2,15.047) (topology3,14.047)(topology4, 12.047) (topology5,12.047)};


        \legend{MARA-MC,MARA-MMMF,MARA-SPE}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Running your code I end up with a graph where topology2 is clearly greater than topology3. What's the problem? Perhaps provide an image showing what you have and an illustration of what you want.

Comment: @penguinpreferred  hello, the problem in topology 2 comparing to topology 1, first bar shows 15 iterations, and 2 and 3 bar from topology 2 are not exactly 15, the 14.047 was rounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the graph height and y axis bounds to "magnify" the data. I have make the graph 18cm high, with ymin=8.5 and ymax=19. That displays your difference.

However, this may not be the best solution. Given the small size of the difference, you may wish to consider either explaining the data in your text, or representing it differently, perhaps with values on the plot.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn, openright]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}


% Define bar chart colors
%
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
        height = 18cm,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        y tick label style={
                /pgf/number format/fixed
                },
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=12pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {\#iterations},
        symbolic x coords={topology1,topology2,topology3,topology4,topology5},
        xtick = data,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.12,
        ymin=8.5,
        ymax=19,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
 ]
        \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none}]
            coordinates {(topology1, 15) (topology2,12) (topology3,11)(topology4, 9) (topology5,9) };
        \addplot[style={ppurple,fill=ppurple,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(topology1,18.047) (topology2,15.047) (topology3,14.047)(topology4, 12.047) (topology5,12.047)};

        \addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(topology1,18.047) (topology2,15.047) (topology3,14.047)(topology4, 12.047) (topology5,12.047)};


        \legend{MARA-MC,MARA-MMMF,MARA-SPE}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake in my last comment, the 15.047 seems to be rounded or the scale is too small to show the little difference on the plot.

Comment: So, just to be clear, the two figures you wish to distinguish are 15.000 in the blue column of topology1 and 15.047 in the green and purple columns of topology2?

Comment: Yes, it would be great if the green and purple columns of topology 2 are "taller" than the blue column of topology 1

Comment: Thank you @penguinpreferred  I'll add values on the plot :)